# SharePoint Online Site for a Hospital Service

Tags: sharepoint-online, learning

I have been tasked with developing a SharePoint Online site for my service at my hospital. I am an RN and in no way familiar with web and technological jargon.

**Is there a location where I can find very basic and beginner information about how to create a SharePoint for my service?**

Or do I need to already have a higher level working knowledge of information technology?

I have tried to read the beginner SPO information and do not understand the jargon.

Our IT department has not been mandated to support our individual service level needs related to SharePoint Online. However an SPO site for each service will still be created.

Thank you in advance for any information and/or direction you are able to provide.

Answer (score 2):

You should ask your IT to do the following:

- Create standalone Modern Team site for your service. Give them the name of your service.
- Add you as an Owner to the new site.
- Provide the URLs to the new site.

Now, that you are a site owner, you need to do the following:

1. [Optional] Ask an experienced SharePoint Online user to help you. You can even use this forum to do it.
2. Study the basics of SharePoint Online and Microsoft 365.

If you go with the "self-study" option, prepare to spare several hours. [You can use the official Microsoft website to search for the free learning modules](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/). I have created a collection of modules that you can use for studying: [SharePoint Fundamentals](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/users/denismolodtsov-8037/collections/663mh02nkpo03o)
After you finish studying, come back to this forum and ask more specific questions if you still have any. Example of a more specific question:

> I have a group of 35 people. All nurses from the "Service X". We need
> to store the following types of documents: "Rules and regulations",
> "Benefit plans", etc., etc. How would I organise these documents in a
> site?

Comment: Thank you so much!! :) This is very helpful advice.